# Can't explode a method in php

Tags: php, explode, strsplit

What do I missed in my code ?
I tried to explode/split a method but the result is empty array.
Here's my code:

```
function fileName($id){
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM folders WHERE folder_id = ".$id."");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  if($row['parent'] != 0){
      echo $row['folder_name']."_";
      fileName($row['parent']);
  }else{
      echo $row['folder_name'];
  }
}
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
  $count = $_FILES['files']['name'];
  $N = count($count);
  $nama = fileName($_POST['folders']);
  $ex = split("\_", $nama);
  echo "<p>";
  var_dump($ex);
}
```

the result:

```
Jack_Doyou_Uploaded

array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }
```

Comment: your fileName-function does not return anything.

Comment: If you want to split by `_` - use it and not `\_`

Comment: @u_mulder still doesn't work ..

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I'm a bit confused how to return my function..

Comment: @Hendrik Eka via the [return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)-statement, which is a basic element of any programming language with functions

Comment: @FranzGleichmann yeah I know that, but what variable that I need to return ??

Comment: Thanks, I've found the way..